# Problem Deploying new application

Tags: vb.net

Im new to this, so please forgive me. What im doing is deploying my application onto the server, it works fine on my local machine but im getting errors when I try to hit the server. Here is the error below and my web.config file. I dont know what im doing wrong.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 18: <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

Line 19: <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
Line 20:        <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 21:            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
Line 22:        </authentication>



    <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data  
             source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  
             Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User 
             Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" 
             targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, 
             Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
       <clear/>
       <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"    
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
                enablePasswordReset="true" 
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
       <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"  
                 type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
                 connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
    <clear/>
     <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
              connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to recall this happening when you have deployed your application into a sub-folder of an existing site, and it it's `web.config` includes a setting that either applies to the entire site/application, and can't be modified on a per-folder basis

`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level`

I'd play with your

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

setting. Try moving it to the site's root web.config and see where that gets you, or remove it entirely.

Also, see (just from a quick Google)

[Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level)

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx

[ASP.NET IIS Web.config [Internal Server Error]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138285/asp-net-iis-web-config-internal-server-error)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1031775.aspx/1