# IIS 7.5 Giving Configuration Error because of Entity Framework Connection String

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, iis

We have `WCF` service which was hosted at our development IIS server. It was running fine for many weeks. Then we transferred to client's server which was configured by our ICT team and is identical to what we have in house. But on that machine we are getting following error and are not able to figure out what is wrong :(

[image]

Comment: I can recommend some things for you in **iis installation control Panel-> turn win feature on or off -> iis -> WOrld wide web services -> application development ->  check all except CGI then ok** and install. this may help you. I'm not pretty sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d Have you seen this ?