# Deployment on local machine - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy an asp.net core web app to my local machine but it gives me the following error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d. 
It is the first time I'm attempting it, so I don't understand what is the problem. 
Searching for solutions, I have found out that there is malformed xml element in the web.config file but since I have never done it, I couldn't understand how to fix this.

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
       <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
               <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
          </handlers>
          <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
     </location>
   </configuration>
  <!--ProjectGuid: 110a64bf-38d2-4b16-8536-814161f00f23-->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There was a problem in the format of the code when I was writing the document, it's a typo, the tag is there in the real file. I have changed the question. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d)

Answer (score 0):

It was giving a problem because it is a asp.net core app. 
I followed the instructions in these links:
https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2