# How to fix the 500.19 - Internal server error with error code 0x8007000d

Tags: iis-8

I have configured an .Net application in IIS, while launching the application I'm receiving an error as "500.19- internal server error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid." with error code 0x8007000d.
This is my web.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
                <clear />
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
    value="Development" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I have installed all the prerequisite
Installed the .Net framework 4.5.1 
Installed the URL rewrite 
Tried with the iis_iusrs permissions
Installed the web hosting bundle

Could you please help me to resolve this error. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d)

Comment: I tried with the suggestions given in the above link, but still facing the same error.

Comment: Run a report and edit your question to include that, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete the space in front of the XML Declaration (the first line) and try again.  If that doesn't work, then be sure to post all relevant details of the error message.  Your error page likely tells you precisely what line your error is line.

Comment: There was no space in the XML Declaration.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x8007000d
Config Error    
Config File \\?\C:\Websites\Portal\Root\web.config

Answer (score 0):

I struggled on this error for longer than I should have.

Installing the URL rewriting module via web platform installer instantly solved the issue for me.

Just install this:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: This might be the solution for you, but posting such an answer here is completely against the question you raised. What exactly was the actual error page and what was the configuration file it complaints about? If installing URL Rewrite module was the solution, then it must complaint about XML element of `<rewrite>`, but not  `<aspNetCore>`.