# IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iis, localhost

IIS Have FULL Control On Folder And Webconfig And Have All Permissions
And When I Trying to Start Website I See HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

with This Code 0x8007000d

And I Know Nothing Wrong With Webconfig

(All Of my Websites Have This Problem)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITfYw.png)
And When I Trying Open Any Components in IIS Features View I See This Error

(There Was An Error While Performing this operation.
Details:

Filename:\?\C:\Users\110pc\wwwroot\DivarService\web.config

Errors:)

I'm tired Can Anyone Help?

Comment: [Possibly this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18788068/3181933). I've seen others related to ASP.NET Core, but since you're not using that I guess this one is the most likely. No idea if it will fix your problem though, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should provide more details on this. Are you using Visual Studio F5? Show us the web.config. Do you see any call stack in the error? ...

Comment: No It is not Run in Visual Studio

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html#background 500.19 with `0x8007000d` is so well known.

Answer (score 0):

I installed asp core hosting module and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

**#The Solution#**

1 . Install Urlrewrite

2 . set permission iuser and IIS_IUSRS Root Folder

3 . Change Sa Password Sql

4 . Install IIS on The Server Manager Full Package

good louck