# angular and .net core 2.2 Web.config file issue when deploy on IIS windows 10

Tags: .net, angular, iis

I have created an application on angular 6 with .net core. i don't create any  web.config file when i publish the code its automatically generate the web config file with following code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
     <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ITERP.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
               stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

when i deploy that on IIS on windows 10 its generate error that 
**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
Error Code     0x8007000d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d

Comment: ---------------------------
URL Rewrite
---------------------------
There was an error while performing this operation.



Details: 

Filename: \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

Error: 


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------  I already installed but got this error when click on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET: HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d)

Comment: The error message means xml is not resolved completely. Have you installed the correct webhosting bundle ?https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2.  If that is not working, please post a screenshot to the full detailed IIS error message.

Comment: yes i have change in web config now for URL rewrite its work now but still website not working fine I enable the option Browse directory and it will show the files and folder but i am not able to open the login or index page of angular 6 with .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Its obviously that extensionless handler won't work for the asp.net core application.

Please ensure .net core web hosting bunddle has been installed and the aspnetCore handler has been created.

[image]

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
```

Comment: I did not find AspNetCoreModuleV2 in modules can you please guide me

Comment: @SheikhSaad Did you forgot to deploy the .net core via web deployment tool? Because by default web deployment tool will register handler in IIS. If you didn't deploy it via web deployment tool, the handler would missing. Then you may need to create the handler via IIS manager->site node->hanlder mappings or rigister  aspnetcore handler in <handlers> section.

Comment: I publish Code using VS 2019 and Set IIS web path on that folder then i Publish angular code using ng build -- prod and past it in that folder Login page is open now but cannot access the web Api "IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found" error . i create a server certificate using IIS and try again but no success. I did all that on windows 10 and IIS 10 on local machine.