# IIS 10 can't read web.config (try to deploy Blazor), Error 500.19 with 0x8007000d

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, web-deployment

i have a problem deploying Blazor in IIS 10 (Windows 2019 Server, Version 1809).

What i did:

1. create a Blazor Project in Visual Studio (i used the default project, so i don't expect any programming issues here). It runs in VS (IIS Express). I used "Blazor WebAssembly App" (not "Blazor-Server-App") and i checked ASP.NET Core hosted.
2. i published the app to a folder. It contains lots of dll's, especially the "test.Client.dll", "test.Server.dll", "test.Shared.dll" and "web.config". It also contains 2 folders: BlazorDebugProxy and "wwwroot".
3. in IIS, i added the folder as an application.

What happens is: i get a HTTP Error 500.19 with error code 0x8007000d, which means that IIS can't read the "web.config".

I did not make any changes to the "web.config", it comes directly from Visual Studio, so i don't think it is a problem with the xml.

Here is what i already tried:

- install URL Rewrite 2
- give IIS_IUSRS the rights to the folder
- add roles and features in the server: .NET 4.7, ASP.NET 4.7, HTTP Redirection, WebDAV

Does anybody have an idea what to do next?

I also wonder, if there is a way to find out, what bothers IIS exactly. The logfiles under C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\ seem to only log the HTTP requests and in Windows cmd -> "eventvwr" it does not show the error either.

Thanks a lot,
Tim

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d. Also, can you post the web.config file if the previous link didn't help?

Comment: Oh my god, installing the runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle did the trick for me :) Thanks a lot!

The link is: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

I somehow thought this would be standard on a Windows 2019 Server and the download would only be necessary if you try to do it on Windows 10... my bad.