# ASP.NET Core MVC / C# : server error during loading main page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, server-error

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC website written in C#. When I try to run the program in localhost it works.

But when I load it on the release server, I get this error. Why?

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Possible solution: [how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

Comment: Another based on the error code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836473/asp-net-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007000d

Comment: `"I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC website"` there are lot of additional configurations related to this.  Firstly, where are you trying to publish? `IIS` or `Azure`? 
If `IIS` then which version? Do you have any special configuration within your application? For instances, `URL Rewrite` or anything? 
These informations are prerequisite to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I'm using IIS. i don't have any special configuration ... If i create a basic file index.html it works but if i try to publish the ASP.NET core it give me that error

Comment: Could you also add which CLR your application pool is running?