# How to solve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" "<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to upload my webapi to iis but i am getting the following error:

[image]

```
Config Source:
   24:     </modules>
   25:     <handlers>
   26:       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
```

Here is my webconfig file:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I am using windows 8.1. I have installed all features of IIS.

My application pool is:

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Comment: check the version of .Net framework with app pool

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are two things to check that you have appropriate installed .Net. And also the following configurations are checked.

[image]

Comment: But why we require Application development features in production. Aren't they meant only for development?

Comment: @user2692032 feel free to adapt based on your requirement. You don't need CGi for production obviously

Comment: Only ASP.NET is required to be added, to fix the issue, actually

Answer (score 11):

You need to check these things. if your site is hosted on Windows Server 2008, 2012/R2 and 2016.

[image]