# HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021 while configuring IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to configure IIS server but I get this error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

**Detailed Error Information:**

**Module** IIS Web Core

**Notification** BeginRequest

**Handler** Not yet determined

**Error Code** 0x80070021

**Config Error** This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

**Config File** \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LinedataHandyPartner\web.config

> Config Source:

```
   52:     </handlers>
   53:     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   54:       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
```

Comment: As per the error message, have you tried unlocking the system.webServer/modules config section?

Comment: Solution: I faced similar issue and finally this thread helped me, pretty simple solution though.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821187/how-to-solve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-remove-name-extensio

Answer (score 5):

To unlock IIS configuration for module settings, enter the following commands in an elevated PowerShell context.

```powershell
Import-Module WebAdministration

Set-WebConfiguration `
  -Filter "/System.webServer/modules" `
  -Metadata overrideMode `
  -Value Allow `
  -PSPath "IIS:\"
```

Comment: I was seeing the OP's error when attempting to load a WCF service. Running this script moved the <modules> section later in the IIS applicationHost.config file but didn't change any values. Curiously, it resolved the issue. Thanks!