# Could not start ASP.NET debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

on debugging a website as a start up project in visual studio the following error is showing:
[image]

and an internal server error (500.19) while setting the webApi as a startup project

Comment: Use Jexus Manager to run the project and it should reveal more about the problem. There is also a diagnostic tool https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! The below answer is a possible solution too. @LexLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was with enabling the world wide web services in Windows Features under the Internet Information Services (IIS) [The solution here solves this problem too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821187/how-to-solve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-remove-name-extensio).